# swap bits position in linux

Tags: shell, binary, hex

i have hex value

```
B455
```

when i change it to binary i got

```
1011 0100 0101 0101
```

i want to swap the bits with a rule of :

```
origin bits index : 0123456789ABCDEF
result bits index : D5679123C4EF80AB`
```

then i have result

```
1100 1011 0001 1101
```

to hex is

```
CB1D
```

can you help to get script shell do this ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: So `B` becomes `F` looking at  your origin/result index.  How does it become `C` in your desired answer ?

Comment: A shell script may not be the best tool for this. Maybe a Perl script or a short C program?

Answer (score 1):

As noted, the shell is probably not the best place to do this.  If you really want to, here's a solution using `awk`, `dc`, `printf`, `sed`, and `tr`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# file: swap-bits

target_order='D5679123C4EF80AB'
indices() {
    printf '%s\n' "$1"         \
    | sed 's/./\0 1+p\n/g'     \
    | sed '1s/^/10o16i/'       \
    | dc                       \
    | sed 's/^/substr( $0, /'  \
    | sed 's/$/, 1 )/'         \
    | tr '\n' ' '
    echo
}

sed 's/^/2o16iF/'                                              \
| sed 's/$/p/'                                                 \
| dc                                                           \
| sed 's/....//'                                               \
| awk "{ print \"16o2i\" $(indices ${target_order}) \"pq\" }"  \
| dc                                                           \
| sed 's/^/0000/'                                              \
| sed 's/.*\(....\)$/\1/'
```

This does no checking of the input.
The `target_order` variable should be set to the preferred permutation of your 16 bits.

The function `indices` takes as input such a string, and outputs a sequence of `substr( $0, n, 1 )` commands, which `awk` will use to permute its input.

The main body of the script begins by using `dc` to convert the input from hexadecimal to binary.  Leading zero-bits are preserved by prefixing the input with F and discarding the four one-bits.  The result is fed to `awk`, which prints a command that tells `dc` to convert from binary to hexadecimal, then the permuted output, then a command that tells `dc` to print and quit.  This is of course fed into `dc`.  Finally, `sed` is used again to ensure leading zeroes exist in the output if appropriate.

Input comes on `stdin`, output on `stdout`, like so:

```
$ echo B455 | ./swap-bits
CB15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -wMstrict -le '
   my @bits = unpack "(A1)16", sprintf "%016b", hex shift;
   my $bitmap = "D5679123C4EF80AB";
   @bits = @bits[ map { hex } split //, $bitmap ];
   $"="";
   print sprintf "%04X", oct "0b@bits";
' "B455"
```

`Result: CB15`

## Brief:

```
First we convert the input hex number into it's 16-bit binary equivalent and store the indi-
dual bits in the array @bits. The individual bits are now mapped according to the bitmap wh-
ich is generated by splitting into single bits and getting their decimal equivalents which
are the array indices of @bits. Last step involves in converting the mapped bits into their
4-digit hex counterpart.
```